# Combining multiple line geometries into a single geometry

Tags: three.js

I am completely new to Three.js and I am try to add edges to solid models.

The problem is if I add the edges individually the rendering becomes slow. So thinking of combining the geometries into a single so that the rendering speeds up a bit.

I came across this : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1370
But the output is not remaining correct after using above technique.

My code so far below:

```
/* Edge Data */
var vertices = edgeData.vertices;
var edges = edgeData.edges;

// Final Geometry
var combinedGeo = new THREE.Geometry();

/* Add lines */
for( var i=0; i<edges.length; i++){
    var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
    for (var j=0; j<edges[i].length; j++){
        var v1 = vertices[edges[i][j]];
        geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v1[0], v1[1], v1[2]));
    }

    // var line = new THREE.Line(geom, material, THREE.LinePieces);
    THREE.GeometryUtils.merge( combinedGeo, geom);
    // scene.add(line);
}
var edgesGeo = new THREE.Line(combinedGeo, material, THREE.LineStrip);
scene.add(edgesGeo);
```

Comment: No merging is required. Add pairs of points to your `geometry` first, and then create one `Line` with the `LinePieces` setting. See the AxisHelper.js code, for example.

Comment: You can also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773982/how-to-merge-multiple-lines-with-gaps-in-threejs

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for the solution. It worked. Somehow the geometry was getting cached so took a bit of time to verify.

Comment: Great! I turned my comment into an answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No merging is required. Add pairs of points to your `geometry` first, and then create one `Line` with the `LinePieces` setting. See the `THREE.AxisHelper` code, for example.